# Windows Hostname From File System

Tags: windows, filesystems, computer-name

How can I determine the hostname of a Windows (XP) computer from files alone?

I have a full backup of several hard drives.  I'm not sure which one is which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could open a copy of the SYSTEM registry file in the Registry Editor and browse to:

```
CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName
```

Answer (score 1):

Plug the drive in as a secondary drive and go to: Start > Run > regedit > under File go to Load Hive > select the secondary drive and browse to `\windows\system32\config\`. I use

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

The default domain name contains your PC name (even on PCs that are not members of a domain).

Uslackers key also works for this purpose - just remember it is under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and not `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG`.